# Не работает проброс портов между хостовой ОС и гостевой ОС

Tags: linux, сеть, virtualbox, nat

**Задача:** Имеется хостовая ОС Windows 10 и гостевая ОС Oracle OS развернутая на Virtual Box. Необходимо передать любое http сообщение из Windows 10 в Oracle OS и обратно.

**Как я пробовал решить задачу:** сперва я решил передать http сообщение из хостовой ОС в гостевую (из Windows 10 в Oracle OS). Для этого:

1. настроил проброс портов NAT в настройках ОС предоставляемых VirtualBox (у хостовой ОС выбрал порт 10080, а у гостевой 23080).
2. далее в Oracle OS (гостевая ОС) запустил утилиту NetCat: `nc -l localhost 23080`.
3. затем в Windows 10 (хостовая ОС) запустил postman и из него отправил http GET запрос `http://localhost:10080/somepath`

**Я ожидал:** в консоли гостевой ОС появится какое-то сообщение

**Фактическое поведение:** ничего. В консоли ничего не появилось.

Comment: > настроил проброс портов NAT в настройках ОС предоставляемых VirtualBox (у хостовой ОС выбрал порт 10080, а у гостевой 23080).

это где вы настроили? и лучше бы вы начали с того, как вообще настроили сеть? какой фаэрвол стоит на Oracle OS?

Comment: Если ничего не путаю, в качестве фаэрвола используется nftables. В его настройках я ничего не менял.

Comment: А обязательно NAT? Сетевой мост не подойдёт?

Comment: Я выбрал NAT, т.к. он проще в настройке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все было просто. Достаточно было настроить фаервол - открыть порт на котором работает приложение.

Comment: Я правильно думаю, что порт в файерволе пришлось открыать на гостевой ос?

Comment: Да. Все правильно.